# How to use Multi-Select filter in PrimeNG table.?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to implement the [`multiselect`](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) in primeng table, Following I have tried

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

tableHeader= [
            { 'field': 'type', 'header': 'Type' },
            { 'field': 'value', 'header': 'Value' },
            ];

tableValue = [
    {'type':'A1','value':'row1'},
    {'type':'A1','value':'row2'},
    {'type':'A2','value':'row3'},
    {'type':'A2','value':'row4'},
    {'type':'A1','value':'row5'},
  ];

statusOptions = [
      { 'label': 'A1', 'value': 'A1' },
      { 'label': 'A2', 'value': 'A2' }
  ];

}
```

and html file is

```
<p-table [columns]="tableHeader" [value]="tableValue" [sortOrder]="1"
[responsive]="true" rowHover="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,25]" alwaysShowPaginator="false" [rows]="10"
sortMode="multiple" #tdv>
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of tableHeader" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
            <span>{{col.header}}</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of tableHeader" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
          <p-multiSelect [options]="statusOptions" *ngIf='col.field =="type"' (onChange)="tdv.filter($event.value,col.field,'equals')"></p-multiSelect>
        </th>

    </tr>
</ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.type}}</td>
        <td>{{row.value}}</td>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I am trying to filter the value with `A1` and `A2`. But If I select the single value it is working but if I select the multiple value it is not working. I don't know how to fix this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mutlisect` value when selecting A1 and A2 is `"A1,A2"`  so you need to use `in` instead of `equals`:

```
 <p-multiSelect [options]="statusOptions" *ngIf='col.field =="type"' (onChange)="tdv.filter($event.value,col.field,'in')"></p-multiSelect>
```